# What's the Big O complexity of a ever decreasing range on a for loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, big-o

I got 2 nested `for` loops, I calculate a new value for `nrResults` on every execution of the inner `for` loop (which will loop `nnrResults` - 2 times).

The time complexity should be of order `O(n)`, since `nrResults` depends on the value of `n`.
But `nrResults` is being decreased on every loop of the outer `for` loop.(i.e.  `firstNext * j`    is growing with every iteration)

Is the time complexity of the inner `for` loop still `O(n)` even though `nrResults` will keep decreasing throughout execution?

```java
for(int j = 1; j < B; j++)                      // General case
{
    nrResults = n - (firstNext * j);
    result = codedInput[0] + results[minI = minIndex(results, 0 + firstNext, nrResults + firstNext)];
    
    for(int i = 1; i < nrResults; i++)
    {
        if( (i + firstNext) > minI)
            results[i] = codedInput[i] + results[minI = minIndex(results, i + firstNext, nrResults + firstNext)];
        else
            results[i] = codedInput[i] + results[minI];

        if(results[i] < result)
            result = results[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: The inner loop runs `nResults - 1` times, and since `nResults < n`, it runs at most `n` times, which is O(`n`). Remember, big O notation is not a tight bound. It's also O(`n`^2). Total complexity is just math. sum(`n - j * firstNext` for `j = 1..B`). [Answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum(n+-+j*f,+j++%3D+1..B)).

Comment: You can use little O notation to describe “strictly lower” relations. Like if you have a loop that will always run less than n times, you can say its little o(n)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you have one loop i:=0..n, and an inner loop j:=0..i-2. Is that so?

Complexity of inner loop will be O((n-1)/2), which is the average. Complexity of external for is O(n).

All you have to do is multiply O((n)*(n/2)), i.e. O(n²/2).

In case inner for iterations is different, you have to recalculate it.